# Hover effect lost when mouse is on border

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hover effect does not work when my mouse is on bottom border.
How exactly i can put bottom border to go into list container and count as one element?
At the current moment - when your mouse is on bottom border, element loses hover effect.

```
<style>
 li.nav-item:hover{
 border-bottom:5px solid yellow;
 }
 </style>

 <body style="height:1500px">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz96qg3x/)

Comment: for me the hover effect is still there when the cursor is on the yellow border in the fiddle you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply the style to the `a` instead:

```
li.nav-item a:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go like this, so the link's height wont change by the border-bottom and the navbar won't toggle on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/qra0f3bk/6/

```
li.nav-item a:hover{
  position: relative;
}
li.nav-item a:hover::after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding margin-bottom should solve too, hover effect is gone if there is no margin down there.